# NSMutableDictionary not working in voids and IBActions

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary

I created an `NSMutableDictionary` called `*temp` in my `.h` file of the main viewController, and added this code to bring in the information from my `.plist` file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    temp=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

In the same view controller, I added a button action and added the following code:

```
-(IBAction)mathButton:(UIButton *)_sender
{
    label1.text = [temp objectForKey:@"m1name"];
}
```

Where "label1 is a text field in the `.xib`, and `m1name` is one of the keys in the `.plist`

But when I run it, it doesn't work, and highlights `label1.text = [temp objectForKey:@"m1name"];` and calls it bad access.

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days, and tried lots of things. An answer would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

You're not retaining the dictionary created via `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path`. You should either change that line to:

```
temp = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] retain];
```

(and make sure it's released in `dealloc`), or, if `temp` is a property, set it via

```
self.temp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

In .h:

```
@interface ...
{
    NSMutableDictionary* temp;
}
```

In .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Data"
                                                     ofType: @"plist"];

    BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: path];

    if (exists)
    {
        temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
        NSLog(@"%@", [temp description]);
    }
}

- (IBAction) mathButton: (UIButton *)_sender
{
    label1.text = [temp objectForKey: @"m1name"];
}
```

If MRC:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [temp release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```